# Oracle: After update Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have 3 tables:

```
Category(CategoryId, Name)
Product(ProductId, Name, Description, CategoryId)
OrderItem(OrderId, OrdinalNumber, ProductId, CategoryId)
```

I want to create an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger that changes `CategoryId` (based on new `ProductId)` in `OrderItem` after update of `ProductId` in `OrderItem`.

Can somebody help with this trigger?

Comment: How would you know which category ID to use for a given product? They only seem to be linked in the table you're updating. If they're linked somewhere else - if category ID as actually in your product table now - you wouldn't usually want to duplicate it, you'd look it up as needed via a join.

Comment: Product is from one category. I edited my question. Yes I know i wouldn't usualy want to duplicate it, but I need it duplicated because of db optimization.

Comment: The term "db optimization," like the phrase "provide for the general welfare" in the Constitution, is the source of much mischief. Not knowing your particulars, I obviously cannot dispute your claim, but experience has shown me that 90+% of the time, it is unwarranted. A lot of extra effort by many (like your trigger problem) for very little, if any, performance gain. Let me guess. It's an obstinate DBA who absolutely refuses to consider any changes. You got the expression "db optimization" from him, didn't you?

Comment: I have to do this because its task for my studies. I also, don't preffer it. Expression I got from my professors. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicating the category ID in the order line isn't something you'd usually want to do, but if you're set on that, you need a 'before' trigger, not an 'after' one - since you need to change a value in the row being updated:

```
create or replace trigger orderitem_cat_trig
before insert or update on orderitem
for each row
begin
  select categoryid
  into :new.categoryid
  from product
  where productid = :new.productid;
end;
/
```

I've made it both insert and update on the assumption you'll want to set the value for new order items too.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you like database deadlocks, general performance issues, data corruption and unpredictable results, this type of updates is not advisable. If your performance is a problem, check indexes and queries. Do not replicate your columns in tables, especially not when they're part of an foreign key. I'm not the dogmatic type, but in this case I will not budge ;-)